# Multiple cursors at the same word

Tags: visual-studio-code

You can see that it put multiple cursor at #customers and change them at the same time:
https://youtu.be/hson9BXU9F8?t=885
[image]

How to achieve that in VSCode?

Comment: in find dialog `Alt+Enter`

Answer (score 3):

Selects the word under the cursor or the current selection's next occurrence.

```
Ctrl+D
```

To place cursors next to all instances of a highlighted word

```
Ctrl+Shift+L
```

Comment: `Command+D` on OS X